# Custom Camera Compatibility

Tags: android, camera, instagram

I'm developing an app that uses a the `android camera` but not the `default camera`, I am using a custom one. Everything seem to be fine on my testing device (a local manufactured smart phone). But I'm having problems when it comes to high end devices like Samsung and Sony Xperia, some models from these devices are working fine but with other models no luck (specially large size devices). I guess that the errors are caused by different camera hardware since each android devices has its own hardware camera different with other devices (correct me if im wrong).

But I'm wondering how did `INSTAGRAM` do this trick that their camera is compatible with almost every android phones. Did they used any library or something? Please help me if you know how they did the trick. And is there any standards like on what device should I start developing so if I test my app on other high end device there would be no problems. Also please give me links of standard custom camera that works on every kind of android devices.

Comment: create custom camera by keeping this doc as reference.long back i created custom camera while creating app similar to instagram.it works fine for me.please dont forget to close your camera on onPause life cycle and call it again in onResume    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Thank for the info mate, I'll try this immediately. But you know any stable library or something please refer it to me. Thank you. :) @Ruban

Comment: personally i think custom camera is not a big deal. Android has provided privilege to access all controls in camera like zoom,focus,face detection etc. so i prefer to create own custom camera rather than go for library.  i have shared links below for custom camera library you can use it if you want https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Comment: http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/14/cwac-camera-an-easier-way-to-take-photos-in-android/

Comment: That's very kind of you mate. Thank you very much. @Ruban